# CoveoJsSearch.Lazy.Min.js - Give any one suggestion to improve Google Page Speed Insights score on the sitecore platform

Tags: sitecore, coveo

We have facing the page performance and getting less page score for both mobile & desktop. We would require tips for optimization and improve the page score in the Google Page Speed insights. We have using Sitecore based application.

Also, I have listed below criteria impact on the Page Speed Insights

1. Reduce JavaScript execution time
2. Avoid long main-thread tasks

Comment: Will be hard to give recommendations if we don't have more information about your setup, third party app installed, tools/tech's version, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that using the CoveoJsSearch.Lazy.min.js is the best performance bundle Coveo can offer at the moment if your search interface is built with the Coveo JavaScript Search Framework.

However, if speed is a major concern, you could use the Coveo Headless Library to build the search interface. Coveo Headless is a library for developing Coveo-powered UI components. Keep in mind that this would require a lot of work.

Here is some documentation:[Use the Coveo Headless Library](https://docs.coveo.com/en/headless/latest/)